# Undefined variable: post (View: /home/e/Images/123/test1/resources/views/post.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I was created post create is it work. I try to adding for can edit post and delete, but i have error undefined variable.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\PostImage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['categories'] = Category::all();
        return view('post', $data);
    }

    public function savePOst(Request $request)
    {
//        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file2->extension();
//        $rs = $request->file2->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);
//
//        dd($rs);
//        die;

        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->desc = $request->desc;
        $post->category_id = $request->category;

        if ($post->save()) {

            $postId = $post->id;

            if ($request->hasFile('file1')) {
                $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.' . $request->file1->extension();
                $request->file1->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);

                $postImage = new PostImage();
                $postImage->image = $imageName;
                $postImage->main = 1;
                $postImage->post_id = $postId;
                $postImage->save();
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('file2')) {
                $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.' . $request->file2->extension();
                $request->file2->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);

                $postImage = new PostImage();
                $postImage->image = $imageName;
                $postImage->main = 0;
                $postImage->post_id = $postId;
                $postImage->save();
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('file3')) {
                $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.' . $request->file3->extension();
                $request->file3->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);

                $postImage = new PostImage();
                $postImage->image = $imageName;
                $postImage->main = 0;
                $postImage->post_id = $postId;
                $postImage->save();
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('file4')) {
                $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.' . $request->file4->extension();
                $request->file4->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);

                $postImage = new PostImage();
                $postImage->image = $imageName;
                $postImage->main = 0;
                $postImage->post_id = $postId;
                $postImage->save();
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('file5')) {
                $imageName = uniqid().time() . '.' . $request->file5->extension();
                $request->file5->move(public_path('img/portfolio'), $imageName);

                $postImage = new PostImage();
                $postImage->image = $imageName;
                $postImage->main = 0;
                $postImage->post_id = $postId;
                $postImage->save();
            }

            return back()->with('status', 'Post inserted');
        } else {
            return back()->with('status', 'Error');
        }
    }

    public function editPost(Request $requeest){
        DB::table('posts')
            ->where('id', $requeest->id)
            ->update(['post' => $requeest->post]);


        return back()->with('status','Posts been updated');

    }


    public function deletePost(Request $request){
        DB::table('posts')->where('id', '=', $request->id)->delete();

        echo json_encode(200);
    }

}
```

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: abhi
 * Date: 10/10/2020
 * Time: 10:12 PM
 */ ?>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <section style="padding-top:60px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Add New Post
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @if(Session::has('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    {{Session::get('status')}}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <form method="POST" action="{{url('addpost')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="desc">Description</label>
                                    <textarea name="desc" class="form-control">

                                    </textarea>

                                    <label for="category">Post Category</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select Your Post Category</option>
                                        @if($categories != null)
                                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endif
                                    </select>
                                    <br>
                                    <label for="file">Choose Post Main Image</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file1" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile1(this)"/>
                                    <img id="previewImg1" alt="Main image" style="max-width:330px;margin-top:20px;">

                                    <label for="file">Choose Post Image Two</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file2" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile2(this)"/>
                                    <img id="previewImg2" alt="First image" style="max-width:330px;margin-top:20px;">

                                    <label for="file">Choose Post Image Three</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file3" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile3(this)"/>
                                    <img id="previewImg3" alt="Second image" style="max-width:330px;margin-top:20px;">

                                    <label for="file">Choose Post Image Four</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file4" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile4(this)"/>
                                    <img id="previewImg4" alt="Fourth image" style="max-width:330px;margin-top:20px;">

                                    <label for="file">Choose Post Image Five</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file5" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile5(this)"/>
                                    <img id="previewImg5" alt="Fifth image" style="max-width:330px;margin-top:20px;">

                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>

                                <a href="/category" class="btn btn-success">Add New Category</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{url('editpost')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <div class="row mt-5">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @if($post != null)
                                                @foreach($post as $posts)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th scope="row">{{$posts->id}}</th>
                                                        <td>{{$posts->posts}}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2"
                                                                onclick="edit('{{$posts->id}}','{{$posts->posts}}');">Edit
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="del('{{$posts->id}}')">Delete</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                       </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function previewFile1(input) {
            var file1 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file1) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg1').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file1);
            }
        }

        function previewFile2(input) {
            var file2 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file2) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg2').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file2);
            }
        }

        function previewFile3(input) {
            var file3 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file3) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg3').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file3);
            }
        }

        function previewFile4(input) {
            var file4 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file4) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg4').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file4);
            }
        }

        function previewFile5(input) {
            var file5 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file5) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg5').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file5);
            }
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

I created this  project in laravel 8, it's for school i try to learn laravel and symfony i try to understand this systeme someone can help with this error and explain if possible. How I can resolve this error for I can edit and deleted posts, in the same page

Comment: `$data['categories'] = Category::all();return view('post', $data);` to `$data['categories'] = Category::all(); $data['post] =  Post::all();  return view('post', $data);`

Comment: It's leaved error but don't deleted or edited. Now have 419 Page Expired when i try to remove or edit post. how i can resolve this?

Comment: 419 error is page expiry error.
You must have forgotten to add csrf token inside your form.
Add @csrf inside your form. It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

$data['categories'] = Category::all();return view('post', $data); to $data['categories'] = Category::all(); $data['post] =  Post::all();  return view('post', $data);

- need add @csrf